# Hacer consulta con AJAX a BD al insertar dato en INPUT - C#

Tags: c#, html5, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-5

He buscado información en internet pero me confundo un poco,
tengo una etiqueta input.

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label>Stock Number</label><br />
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="StockNumber" name="StockNumber" value="" placeholder="e.g. 1810001" required />
 </div>
```

Me interesa hacer una consulta a la base de datos al ingresar información al input, para saber si ese dato ya existe en la BD mandarle un mensaje al usuario como "Numero de Stock ya existe".
Espero poder recibir su ayuda

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: entiendo que el problema es la comunicacion desde el html al servidor, o sea como realizar la consulta a la db para validar si existe conoces como hacerlo, no?

Comment: mi intención era realizar una consulta al momento de ingresar datos a un input, pero ya lo pude realizar. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacerlo que mencionas debes usar `ajax` podrias hacerlo facilmente por medio de `jquery`, para esto

[Posting Data With jQuery AJAX In ASP.NET Razor Web Pages](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/220/posting-data-with-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-razor-web-pages)

En el articulo veras como utiliza

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Receiver",
    data: car,
    datatype: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    }
});
```

para invocar un action del controller y recibir la respuesta en un json

Comment: Muchas gracias, perdon por no comentar alguien, pero este post era exactamente lo que ecesitaba :)